# How to retrieve magento catalog prices rules with magento API?

Tags: api, magento, soap

I have looked over every Magento SOAP API calls to check if retrieving catalog price rules is possible. Am I missing something here? Or Magento has not implemented this call in the API and that I would have to implement and extend it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right.

Magento CE and EE do not have SOAP/RPC implementations for the `SalesRule` models.

Comment: Thank you for confirming