# Is it possible to retrieve Magento Catalog Price Rules using the REST API (OS/CE2.1.7)?

Tags: rest, magento, magento-rules

Using the Magento OS/CE2.1.7 API I can see the Cart Price Rules (salesRules) but I haven't discovered a way to retrieve the Catalog Price Rules.
Is it possible  to retrieve Magento Catalog Price Rules using the REST API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve magento catalog prices rules with magento API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801856/how-to-retrieve-magento-catalog-prices-rules-with-magento-api)

Comment: Thanks for the update although that answer was for SOAP, not REST, and also almost 3 years old (so would have applied to v1).

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible in CE or EE.

Comment: Please provide some more information, e.g. a link to where to find this information.

Comment: Thanks - I think we eventually settled with building a custom module.